# In bash how to insert a variable in a grep command and affect output to another?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, nested, variable-expansion

I need to use the following grep command in a shell script:

```
grep 'DUE TO TIME LIMIT' ./slurm-3364.out
```

Which outputs the lines in slurm-3364.out containing the pattern 'DUE TO TIME LIMIT'. I want to replace the file name with a variable and affect the output to a another variable. So far I can't get the same result, I tried:

```
jobOver="$(grep 'DUE TO TIME LIMIT' "$NEWEST")"
echo $jobOver
```

With $NEWEST containing the appropriate file name. This produces a very long text output that seems to list every file in the working directory...

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments, doing echo "$jobOver" solved the problem.

Comment: What you've written is certainly *a* correct Bash statement, and it does what you said you want. If what you want is not what that command does, you'll need to give us more precise information about what you want . . .

Comment: Please show an abbreviated input and desired output. Define what you want and don't just say "this doesn't do what I want." How do we know what you want???

Comment: Edited my post. Basicaly both examples give different output.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the script and the value of `$NEWEST` ? I tested it and it seems to do what you expect.

Comment: quote the argument to echo `echo "$jobOver"`.  Using my crystal ball, I can see that the file contains '*' characters in the matched lines.

Comment: Use redirection: `grep 'DUE TO TIME LIMIT' "$file1" > "$file2"` passing `file1` and `file2` as variables (or using `$1` and `$2` positional parameters) You can redirect both ways, e.g. `grep 'DUE TO TIME LIMIT' < "$file1" > "$file2"`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: irrelevant - no, wait, creating a temporary file is actually worse.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question...

Comment: clearly `$NEWEST` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: Then `varname=$(grep 'DUE TO TIME LIMIT' "$file1")` will work.

Comment: The full line that includes what you are grepping reads something like `slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 1234567 CANCELLED AT 2016-01-01T00:00:00 DUE TO TIME LIMIT on somenode001 ***` and those `*`  are expanded when you run `echo $jobOver`, effectively listing the directory content. Running `echo "$jobOver"` instead will give you the expected result, as mentioned by @DavidC.Rankin.

Comment: @damienfrancois and William Pursell, yes that was it. I didn't realize there were '*'s in the grep output and I didn't know they would be expanded! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
jobOver=$(grep 'DUE TO TIME LIMIT' "$NEWEST")
echo "$jobOver"
```

Here, `NEWEST` is the variable containing the name of the file your want to grep.

---

Here is a local test I just ran:

```
$ cat slurm-3364.out
I DIED DUE TO TIME LIMIT, YESTERDAY.
I FEEL GREAT WHERE I AM.
YOU SHOULD JOIN ME.

$ NEWEST="slurm-3364.out"
$ jobOver=$(grep 'DUE TO TIME LIMIT' "$NEWEST")

$ echo "$jobOver"
I DIED DUE TO TIME LIMIT, YESTERDAY.
```

Comment: Yes quoting the argument of echo did the trick. Thanks!